# Robot Framework System Variable inside Variable Yaml file

Tags: python, automation, yaml, robotframework, automation-testing

Is there a way, robot framework system variables can be defined in Variable Yaml file.
For example; I've a yaml file like

testdata.yaml

```
key: ${EXECDIR}${/}mydir
```

Importing file in robot Test Case:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables  testdata.yaml

*** Test Cases ***
TestCase1
  log  key
```

This is literally printing "${EXECDIR}${/}mydir" rather than the value of EXECDIR.

EXECDIR is just an example, I've a requirement to use many robotframework system variables inside yaml in customized way. So I can not use `Replace Variables`.
I've checked an existing question, [How to access a variable inside another variable in yaml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087812/how-to-access-a-variable-inside-another-variable-in-yaml-file/52090582#comment130216718_52090582). But this refers to user defined variable. Is the same limitation applicable for system variables as well?

If it's not possible then I would have to use
Yaml Load and create another variable holding yaml content in Robot framework dictionary.
But I would prefer:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables   testdata.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with the Robot Framework [nested variables](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables-inside-variables). The way you can use this is to have the YAML file look like this

`path/to/data.yml`

```yaml
DATA:
  exec_dir: EXEC_DIR
```

Notice that the variable name is here without any fancy decorations. To reference it inside the Robot script you can use it from the imported dictionary like this.

`test.robot`

```
*** Settings ***
Variables           path/to/data.yml

*** Test Cases ***
Fetch Configuration Data
    [Documentation]     This shows how to use Robot Framework runtime 
    ...                 variables from a variable file.
    Log    The whole dict contains ${DATA}
    Log    The variable name is ${DATA["exec_dir"]} and its value is ${${DATA["exec_dir"]}}
```

Notice the additional `${ }` wrapping around the variable name to make it evaluated correctly.

This actually will work with any variables as long as they are defined before calling them in the Robot - even user defined variables can be called like this but *not* before they are defined in the script. YAML does not provide variable evaluation.

Comment: I'll try with this approach. Appreciate your help!